# Electron JS - Get path of chosen directory

Tags: javascript, electron

Im fairly new in the programming world. I'm making an app where it should be possible to choose a directory, where to save some generated files.

I'm working with the ipc, and it seems like some of the code works, but it looks like i can't get the mainIpc to send the path back to the renderer.

I hope the hive can help, thanks in advance!

**Renderer:**

```
const electron = require("electron");
const ipc = require("electron").ipcRenderer;    

createBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
ipc.send("path:get");
});

ipc.on("path:selected", function (path) {
console.log("Full path: ", path);
});
```

**Main**

```
const ipc = require("electron").ipcMain;
const os = require("os");
const { dialog } = require("electron");

ipc.on("path:get", function (event) {
if (os.platform() === "linux" || os.platform() === "win32") {
    dialog.showOpenDialog(
        {
            properties: ["openFile"],
        },
        function (files) {
            if (files) win.webContents.send("path:selected", files[0]);
            console.log("SENT");
        }
    );
} else {
    dialog.showOpenDialog(
        {
            properties: ["openFile", "openDirectory"],
        },
        function (files) {
            if (files) win.webContents.send("path:selected", files[0]);
            console.log("SENT");
        }
    );
}
});
```

Edit: Adding the setup
**Setup**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

const ipc = require("electron").ipcMain;
const os = require("os");
const { dialog } = require("electron");

try {
    require("electron-reloader")(module);
} catch (_) {}

let win;

function createWindow() {
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
    },
});

win.loadFile("./src/index.html");
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
}
});

app.on("activate", () => {
if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
}
});
```

Comment: are you sure `win` is available where you call it?

Comment: added my setup.
I've declared `win` in the global scope. So im pretty sure that it is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with some kind help.
So if anyone needs the same procedure i'll try to explain what i got to.

So, in the main, i had to add a then, because the showDialog returns a promise

```
if (os.platform() === "linux" || os.platform() === "win32") {
    dialog
        .showOpenDialog({
            properties: ["openFile", "openDirectory"],
        })
        .then((result) => {
            if (result) win.webContents.send("path:selected", result.filePaths);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
} else {
    dialog
        .showOpenDialog({
            properties: ["openFile", "openDirectory"],
        })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.filePaths);
            if (result) win.webContents.send("path:selected", result.filePaths);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

});

This sends back an array with the path at [0]

in the renderer i forgot to add the event as an parameter.

```
ipc.on("path:selected", (event, path) => {
  chosenPath = path;
  console.log("Full path: ", chosenPath[0]);
});
```